# NSUncaughtExceptionHandler when using Realm with Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've got Fabric installed in my app, with Crashlytics enabled via a simple `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])` call in AppDelegate. Everything was working great, until I pulled in Realm. I have a dead-simple function;

```
class func listObjects() {
        let realm = try? Realm()
        if let realm = realm {
            let objSet = realm.objects(TestObject.self)
            print("Retrieved \(objSet.count) objects")
        }
    }
```

Calling the function actually works just fine, but I get an odd warning;

```
[Crashlytics:Crash] Warning: NSUncaughtExceptionHandler is '_ZZ34RLMInstallUncaughtExceptionHandlervEN3$_08__invokeEP11NSException' in '<...>/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm'
```

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is happening because Crashlytics checks whether the uncaught exception handler is overridden, because it is relying on that itself, but it is commonly misused for purposes where there would be less dangerous solutions.

Realm is using this for good reasons: we need to tear down open write transactions. While we are doing that, we still ensure to call the previously configured exception handler as [you can see here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v1.0.1/Realm/RLMRealmUtil.mm#L67-L86). So Crashlytics won't loose it's ability to report any exceptions in your app.